# WebView не грузит определённую страницу

Tags: android, webview, site

WebView не грузит определённую страницу точнее progressbar сайта крутится но так и не загружает страницу вовсе

```
public class EX extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ex);
        web = findViewById(R.id.web);

        web.loadUrl("https://ez.vnmu.edu.ua/");
        // web.loadUrl(getIntent().getDataString());
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Может посоветуете другой WebView с GitHub или других интернет ресурсов?

Comment: Попробуйте включить `javascript` (до загрузки страницы): `web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию в `WebView` `javascript` отключен, но куда же сейчас без него. Включаем:

```
web = findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

web.loadUrl("https://ez.vnmu.edu.ua/");
```